# How to split compact data

Tags: python, excel, split

I have an Excel, looks like below:

[image]

Now, all the numbers and alpha are in the same column and they are compact without space.

I want to split the column into four: first 10 characters in column 1, 11-20 characters in column 2, 21-40 characters in column 3, other characters in column 4.

DO you know how can I do that with Python?

Comment: [CSV](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module should work. Could you please share the excel file?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with `Pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(file_path)

df['part_1'] = df.X1.str.slice(0, 10)
df['part_2'] = df.X1.str.slice(10, 20)
df['part_3'] = df.X1.str.slice(20, 40)
df['part_4'] = df.X1.str.slice(40, None)
```